# Transactional Email and Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, procmail, transactional-email

I have an app written in PHP that I am porting to Meteor. This question is really two parts:

1) Currently, my server forwards all email to a PHP script that parses out the response and inserts it into a database, allowing users to respond to message threads by emailing reply+someidentifier@myapp.com. What is the best way of accomplishing this now that I am using Meteor?

2) From a performance perspective, should I running this on the same server that is hosting my application. Is this scalable?

Comment: Could you give a bit of detail on how your server forwards your mail to php? Is it via REST?

Comment: Using postfix you can use an alias 'email+to+redirect: "| php -q /home/user/full/path/to/your/new/script.php"' and 'php://stdin' to retrieve incoming mail in PHP [jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice it but you're using procmail? I've never done this before but you could tell procmail to put its files into a folder that Meteor can access. Then use the `fs` npm module to parse through these every few minutes & put these into a collection using the server side js.

From there you could make the UI you want to use to reply/make threads, etc.

Comment: Using postfix you can use an alias 'email+to+redirect: "| php -q /home/user/full/path/to/your/new/script.php"' and 'php://stdin' to retrieve incoming mail in PHP [http://jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/]. Does anyone have a solution where you wouldn't have to periodically run a processing task?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with meteor specifically, but I reckon you could use node.js with a DDP client to put it into meteor collections so you could use a meteor app to give the whole thing a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses Mailgun http://www.mailgun.com/ to send email. It's free to send up to 200 email per day.

I never tried it, but Mailgun can also receive email and then call a HTTP POST request to your app (meteor) that contains the information about the mail. With the router package, you should be able to handle this request on the server.

Comment: I think this is a great out of the box solution for test sites, but since I run my own servers, and will be sending a lot of emails, I would prefer the alternative that @Akshat suggested.